# C# Ошибка: данный формат пути не поддерживается

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Пишу сетевое консольное приложение. Вчера написал такой код для преобразования файла в массив байт:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Nikita Krasnov\Pictures\3.png";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Проблема в том, что вчера это работало, сегодня уже выдает ошибку "Данный формат пути не поддерживается". Знаю что звучит нелепо но это так. Или может я что-то пропустил?

Comment: Проверьте, существует ли файл по данному пути. Скорее всего либо файл не существует, либо ошибки в пути.

Comment: Файл существует, путь до файла копировался а не вводился вручную.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что вчера пока я писал и тестировал пересылать разные файлы, пользовался именно этим путем и всё работало. На пробелы не жаловалось.

Comment: @krsnv, попробуйте запустить студию от имени Администратора, открыть проект, скомпилировать файл и проверить, изменилось ли что-то.

Comment: @Alexis запустил от админа, пересобрал решение, даже поменял пути у файла на "D:\\Downloads\\1.mp3" чтобы ни пробелов, ни лишних символов не было. Не помогло. Файл 100% существует.  И кстати час назад ещё стало жаловаться на File.Create("‪D:\\1.mp3")). Тоже неправильный путь. Хотя сами пути верные.

Comment: Ошибка из разряда невозможных. Попробуйте сделать rebuild всему проекту.

Comment: @VladD да я понимаю что тут что-то нестандартное. у меня два проекта (клиент и сервер) в одном решении. ребилд делал и по отдельности проектам и в целом ребилд решения. ничего не помогает. пути правильные но программа упорно не хочет их принимать.

Comment: Ставлю на битую оперативку...

Comment: @PashaPash, cтавлю на вредный антивирус =)

Comment: @Alexis антивируса нет вообще, не пользуюсь ими, и стандартный от Windows 10 отключен. Оператива врядли, потому что с ноутом все нормально, полезли бы другие косяки, да и вряд ли бы так мгновенно перестали работать функции которые используют в параметрах путь к файлу) В общем попробую руками перенабрать проект с нуля, если не заведется то даже не знаю что уже делать

Comment: @krsnv, SmartScreen - отключен? UAC - отключен?

Comment: @krsnv, Visual Studio случайно не 2015?

Comment: @krsnv, так же советую почитать про безопасность Windows 10 - MS там хорошенько нашмондячили, да так - что часть софта тупо перестала на ней работать. По крайней мере на превью версии тестировал.

Comment: @Alexis студия 2015 community, все отключено. но проблему уже решил. просто создал новое решение и руками перепечатал оба проекта. все заработало. в общем люблю программирование)

Comment: @Alexis и большое спасибо за беспокойство, вопрос закрыт)

Comment: @VladD, почитайте про студию 2015 последние два комментария. Это я к вчерашнему нашему обсуждению - стоит или не стоит юзать C# 6.0 и VS 2015, пока ее не отдебажат.

Comment: @Alexis какое отношение к проблеме имеет версия студии? Сама по себе студия 2013, 2012, 2015 - это одна и та же программа, с разным номером версии. Судя по ошибке - у человека побился исходиник. причем так, что вместо : у него появился какой-то другой символ. Версия студии не имеет к этому никакого отношения.

Comment: В VS 2017 такой же глюк. Более того показывает ошибку в .Designer.cs на месте удалённой строчки, на которой уже стоит комментарий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,732

Судя по этому, `:` не на месте

Студия случаем не умирала?

Вариантов решения два: либо файл с исходником пересоздать, либо конвертнуть в UTF8 without BOM

Собственно всё

Comment: "но проблему уже решил. просто создал новое решение и руками перепечатал оба проекта. все заработало. в общем люблю программирование)" Спасибо.

Comment: И виновата во всем недоделанная VS 2015.

Comment: @krsnv, человек старался, потрошил исходники фреймворка. Пометьте как ответ.

Comment: Блин, я не заметил, что решение найдено минута в минуту)) в общем бывает, что кодировка файла слетает, то можно кучу необычных багов найти

Comment: @Alexis причем тут 2015-я? она ничем кроме номера версии от 2013-й не отличается :)

Comment: @PashaPash, да ну))) Только вот почемуто проекты портятся на 2015))) А если честно - сам сталкивался, поэтому такое отношение к 15.

Comment: @Alexis проекты портятся на 2015-й потому что на ней активно работают. Активно работали на 2013-й - проекты портились на ней. активно работали в 2008-й - suo файлы корраптились на ней. Активно работали в 6.0 - глюки компилятора выскакивали на ней. Последние три студии ничем друг от друга не отличаются.

Comment: @Alexis ну да, у топикастера 2015-я. у 95% программистов на C# сейчас 2015-я. Так что вполне логично, что проекты будут в 20 раз чаще портиться в 2015, чем в 2013. Я могу гарантировать, что количество испорченных проектов под Visual C++ 6.0 *в этом году* близко к нулю. Но это ничего не говорит о качестве IDE тех годов.

Comment: @PashaPash, откуда такая стата? Все еще сидят на 2012\2013 VS.

Comment: @PashaPash, так же все же чем то VS отличаются друг от друга. Хотябы теми же новыми фичами, такими как отладчик, компилятор и прочее... Редактор может и не меняли, но легко могли накосячить в другом месте.

Comment: @Alexis откуда у вас такая стата? у меня вот на конторе все под 2015-ю уже давно. Компилятор C# в студии внешний. и общий для всех студий на одной машине. Отладчик - тот же самый, в винде вообще общий механизм отладки. Студии, по сути отличаются только номером версии. Т.е. поменялось по мелочам - движок для запуска тестов в x86 (под x64-тот же), мелкие плюшки в UI отладчика, допечатка на другом механизме чуть-чуть. Но я сомневаюсь, что добавление пару кнопочек в UI отладчика взяло и побило двоеточие в файле :)

Comment: @PashaPash, у Вас в конторе - обновили. У многих других - все еще стоят 2012\2013, поспрашивайте у конкурентов за сигаретой, думаю многие ответят что сидят на 2012\13, по крайней мере у нас так, все на старых сидят =)

Comment: @Alexis ну ок, вот точно такая же ошибка за **2014**-й год: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856821/what-is-causing-notsupportedexception-the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported/24856870#24856870. У человек скопировал путь из эксплорера - и получил невидимый символ в строке. На Windows 8.1 Pro +  VS Ultimate 2013 Update 2. Достаточно в качестве доказательства что 2015-я студия и 10-я винда тут ни при чем?

Comment: @PashaPash, там VS 2013 SP2, сейчас же актуальная SP5, на ней такого не замечено. Вполне возможно что баг перешел по наследству конечно - но не буду спорить, возможно Вы правы.

Answer (score 1):

При копировании пути, особенно если это сделано через окошко свойств винды, вначале строки захватывается непечатаемый символ. Это можно проверить, нажимая стрелку вправо/влево в районе начала строки [...@"C:...]
Курсор будет "залипать" между " и C на одно нажатие.